# File contains a list of commands where each command has a string that needs to be substituted w/ string in a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to pass two files as arguments to my script.

File1.txt contains:

```
host1
host2
host3
```

File2.txt contains:

```
command1 host_name morestuff
command2 host_name mnorestuff
```

How do I extract each item from File1 and substitute each of those items with the match "host_name" in File2 so that I have the output:

```
command1 host1 morestuff
command2 host1 mnorestuff
command1 host2 morestuff
command2 host2 morestuff
command2 host3 morestuff
command2 host3 morestuff
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `awk` script that reads the two files, one after the other, and does the substitution:

```
awk 'FNR == NR { cmd[++n] = $0; next }
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            command = cmd[i]
            sub("host_name", $0, command)
            print command
         } 
    }' File2.txt File1.txt
```

This reads the commands from `File2.txt` into an array called `cmd`.  When reading `File1.txt`, the `host_name` string in each command is substituted by the host name read from the file and the modified command is printed.

The result, given the data in the question, will be

```
command1 host1 morestuff
command2 host1 mnorestuff
command1 host2 morestuff
command2 host2 mnorestuff
command1 host3 morestuff
command2 host3 mnorestuff
```

Comment: can you explain:

```1) cmd[++n] = $0;```
```2)  for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) ```

Just learning Linux/Unix and shell scripting and did a lot of research though not nearly enough. Reading up and watching whatever I can on AWK

Comment: @hernoid `cmd[++n] = $0` adds the current line from `File2.txt` to the end of the array `cmd`. `n` will be the total number of entries in the array, and this number will eventually also correspond to the total number of lines in `File2.txt`. The loop iterates with `i` going from 1 to `n`. In each iteration, the corrent line read from `File1.txt` will be substituted in place of the string `host_name` in `cmd[i]`.

Comment: how could I have these commands execute within the awk script or out into main shell?

Comment: @hernoid The list of commands could be saved to a file and then executed using `sh filename`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read reptext; do
  sed -e "s/host_name/$reptext/" $2
done < $1
```

Should be self explaining. If you need more info's, let me know.

edit: as per Kusalananda's valid comment.